# How to add variable to link

Tags: android, rest, retrofit, retrofit2

i am using retrofit library and I would like to GET weather forecast from OpenWeatherAPI.

I have this.

Base url: http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/

```
@GET("weather?q=&units=&appid=" + API_KEY)
Call<WeatherAPI> getWeatherCity(@Query("city") String city, @Query("units") String units);
```

But I get bad url (I do not know how to repair it) -

> Response{protocol=http/1.1, code=502, message=Bad Gateway,
>   url=http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=&units=&appid=111111111111111111111111&city=&units=metric}

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is in the url.
If we break the URL down you will be able to see the error.

So we have the main body of the url:

`http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather`

then the first param

`?q=` but you havent added anything to it after the =, so this is your first problem.

then:

`&units=` again with nothing after the =, so this is your next problem.

then:

`&appid=111111111111111111111111` this bit is fine.

then:

`&city=` again nothing after =.

then:

`&units=metric` this bit is fine.

So your problem is not passing values to the parameters.

Comment: Yes, but how to pass that values to url?

Comment: with plain text you can do "?q=london" or you can do it with with variables and string concatenation so: String place = "london";  "?q=" + place + "&city=" + ....

Comment: and is this possible? `@GET("weather?q={city}&units={units}&appid=" + API_KEY)
    Call<WeatherAPI> getWeatherCity(@Path("city") String city, @Path("units") String units);` it gives me an error